# read only list with automatic properties

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

is there a way to do this with automatic properties ?

```
private IList<string> List;
    public IList<String> list
    {
        get { return List.ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
        set { List = value; }
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, you should have a look at the naming guidelines here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there is not.  Automatic properties do little more than wrap simple return and assignment statements around a backing field.   The only customization allowed is accessibility.  If you want to do anything other than the most basic property, you'll need to use a full property.

Answer (score 0):

try this

private IList List;
    public IList list
    {
        get { return List.ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
        private set { List = value; }
    }